# Surprising search behaviour

Tags: support, search

I just ran a search for the term "loco2" and I was surprised that a few posts where I had mentioned the term did not show in the results (there were a total of 4 results).

I then ran a search for "loco2.com" and saw a total of 6 results, including the ones I had noticed were missing from the original results.

I'm surprised that the original search did not see the string "loco2" as part of "loco2.com". This behaviour means that users are probably missing out on relevant search results (i.e. they'd need to search for the entire URL separately to the brand name to find all mentions).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's just that search is quite hard to implement well.

Google does such an amazing job that users expect the same quality from all sites but their developers, budgets, and infrastructure can't compete with the resources, expertise, and experience of Google. I think I remember seeing or hearing Joel write or say something to the same effect once in a blog or podcast too.

In fact personally, I very rarely search the site via its own search function. I use Google with the `site:` keyword:

> [Google search for: `loco2 site:travel.stackexchange.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=loco2%20site%3atravel.stackexchange.com)

Comment: OK interesting. I guess I have high expectations because Stack Exchange does such an amazing job with everything else :)